# logstash's dissect plugin about unicode delimiter

Tags: logstash

A piece of data I read from Kafka is like `aaaabbbb\u0000�\u0005{"a":"1"}`,
How to use `\u0000�\u0005` as the delimiter

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit with vim to config file:

use `Ctrl+v` input `u0000` `ufffd` `u0005`

```
filter {
  dissect {
    mapping => {
      "message" => "%{header}^@�^E%{body}"
    }
   }
  json {
    source => "body"
    target => "body"
   }
}
```